# Working on Korean Family History without speaking fluent Korean?

Tags: 20th-century, records, korea

I want to work on my Korean ancestry on my mother's side, but have encountered two obstacles. The first is that I don't speak or read Korean and the second is that I can't find any records or information for my Korean ancestors beyond my great-grandparents.

Is there a way to do this work without knowing Korean? I'm learning it but am far from fluent.

Where can I find records?

Also, does the Korean war and the division of the peninsula pose any challenges for finding records?

My mother is the first to immigrate from S.  Korea to the US.

Comment: Do you have an immigration record to start from in terms of finding out when a particular Korean ancestor reached your current country?  I suspect locating where your Korean ancestor came from in Korea will be the first step to finding more records there.

Comment: Can you tell us where in South Korea your mother immigrated from?  It sounds like it is safe for us to assume that happened during/since the Korean War.

Comment: I learned to slow down my own research for my father's German heritage. Meaning i was jumping over valuable information. Names of places where he lived at the time was different than what was current day city description-